# How to parse text with xml message with zeep?

Tags: python, xml, zeep

As defined in `wsdl`, zeep returns method result as text. This text contains XML data. How to parse this text?

Answer (score 0):

While writing question i found solution:

```
pricetext = proxy.GetPriceList(DEVID)
pricexml = lxml.etree.fromstring(pricetext.encode())
pricedata = client.get_type(pricexml.tag).parse_xmlelement(pricexml, client.wsdl)
```